# Cxf + Spring-boot (org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf

I have spring-boot application with cxf. When I run it I get an exception:

```
[2017.03.01 17:37:35.839 MSK] [DEBUG] [o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl] [main]
[Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.]
[2017.03.01 17:37:35.841 MSK] [DEBUG] [o.a.c.r.DefaultResourceManager]
[main] [resolving resource <org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl/bus> type <interface org.apache.cxf.Bus>]
[2017.03.01 17:37:35.842 MSK] [DEBUG] [o.a.c.r.DefaultResourceManager]
[main] [resolving resource <null> type <interface org.apache.cxf.Bus>]
[2017.03.01 17:37:35.870 MSK] [DEBUG] [o.a.c.b.e.Extension] [main] [Could not load optional extension org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.wsdl11.XMLWSDLExtensionLoader]

org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not create object of extension class org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.wsdl11.XMLWSDLExtensionLoader.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:241)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.loadAndRegister(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:213)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.getBeansOfType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:348)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBeanLocator.getBeansOfType(SpringBeanLocator.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.setBus(WSDLManagerImpl.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
```

skip some lines and

```
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: null
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Dependencies of cxf and spring-boot

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-management</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

spring-boot - 1.4.1
cxf - 3.1.7

Please help!! How can I find a bug?

Comment: Can you please add cxf configuration as well here. The first and last dependencies are optional

Comment: Looks like there are some jar conflicts in your project. You only need `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-hc</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>` for cxf jaxws.

Comment: Hey Olga, just curious, why don't you accept my answer here? I am 100% sure it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have multiple `asm` dependencies in your project. You can find them by executing `mvn dependency:tree` from root project, or by looking into artifact after project build.
For using with CXF 3.x you should have dependency `org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.x.x` and greater.

Hope that helps.